# Check IIS is installed and running

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

In our application we want to identify whether iis is installed in a machine. If installed, then we need identify whether it is running.

Is there any way to get this details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Using Managed Code to Detect if IIS is Installed and ASP/ASP.NET is Registered](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18301/Using-Managed-Code-to-Detect-if-IIS-is-Installed-a)

**IIS running or not check below code**

Just add a Reference for "System.ServiceProcess" to your Project.

```
    ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("World Wide Web Publishing Service");
if ((sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) || sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending))) {
    Console.WriteLine("Starting the service...");
    sc.Start();
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Stopping the service...");
    sc.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Is the service name "W3SV" is common to all iis like iis5.0,iis6.0 etc?

Comment: Mine crashed when using 'World Wide Web publishing'. Appending 'service' to that got it to work. It also works with 'W3SVC'

Comment: I found out a situation in which the code from CodeProject will not work. My friend has machine without IIS, but entries in registry exists. I don't know why, maybe it was uninstalled incorrectly. So my point is to detect also IIS service to be sure if it is installed.

Comment: What is service name is in other language than English? Your solution will not work.