# IIS registry is still there even it is disabled

Tags: c#, iis

I have a program that needs IIS 7 or above for the prerequisite. I use the registry with Software\Microsoft\InetStp to check. However, QA got back to me that they got the false positive answer for IIS, that is, IIS is really not there but my program detected it is there (because the IIS registry is there) so it tried to install the program that requires IIS and installation ended up failed. They told me that they disabled IIS and tested and it failed also.

So did some testing. I first looked at my registry and made sure that the IIS was there. Then I disabled my IIS (IIS 7.5 in windows 7 Enterprise) and restarted the computer as asked and checked the registry again, the Software\Microsoft\InetStp path still there with IIS 7.5. That's why the program installation failed because it checked the registry and thought IIS was there but it was really disabled.

I checked all over the internet and all said the registry path is the way to check if IIS is there. It is obvious not reliable in my case. Are there any other ways to check if IIS is really installed and enabled?

Comment: Probably you should check whether the components are there, https://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/discover-installed-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend checking that the service is installed and running as suggested in this SO thread:

[Check IIS is installed and running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816751/check-iis-is-installed-and-running)